# How to filter queryset by two lookups of the same field?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm building a tinder-like app. Here is a model represents review from one user to another:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    like_from = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='outcome_likes')
    like_to = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='income_likes')
    is_positive = models.BooleanField()

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.like_from} -> {self.like_to}'
```

Now I'm trying to filter all matches and all I have is this code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return CustomUser.objects.filter(income_likes__like_from=self.request.user, income_likes__is_positive=True)\
        .filter(outcome_likes__like_to=self.request.user, outcome_likes__is_positive=True)
    # I also tried to go from the opposite side but 
    # also had no idea how to get correct solution
    # Here should be some code to get intersection 
    # of these two querysets's values lists
    # positive_likes_from = self.request.user.income_likes.all().filter(is_positive=True).values('like_from')
    # positive_likes_to = self.request.user.outcome_likes.all().filter(is_positive=True).values('like_to')
```

But uncommented line here will return users that have any positive outcome likes with no guarantee that they will be addressed to the current user.
I want to get a queryset of `CustomUser` model that have positive income and outcome likes with a current user on another side.
Here is an solution of my problem that requires tons of SQL queries to the database:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    positive_likes_from = self.request.user.income_likes.all().filter(is_positive=True)
    positive_likes_to = self.request.user.outcome_likes.all().filter(is_positive=True)
    result = []
    for like in positive_likes_from:
        outcome_like_with_same_user_on_another_side = positive_likes_to.filter(like_to=like.like_from).first()
        if outcome_like_with_same_user_on_another_side:
            result.append((like, outcome_like_with_same_user_on_another_side))
    return result
```

Comment: You can intersect two Querysets using the `&` operator (a QuerySet is a python set), so if you create a `values_list('like_from', flat=True)` and a `values_list('like_to', flat=True)` you should be able to get the intersection of the two.

Comment: Please form it as an answer. It's a proper solution for my problem and I'd like to check it as a correct answer. Thanks. P.S. Your solution will return the ids of users that I look for. Please, add to your answer line that will convert them to Users queryset like `return CustomUser.objects.filter(id__in=qs1.intersection(qs2))`. (Intersection by way you suggested raises error `{TypeError}Merging 'QuerySet' classes must involve the same values in each case.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intersect two `QuerySets` using the `intersection` function or the `&` operator (a QuerySet is a python set) as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#intersection).

So if you create two `QuerySets` for the outgoing likes and incoming likes:

```
qs1 = self.request.user.income_likes.filter(is_positive=True).values_list('like_from', flat=True)
qs2 = self.request.user.outcome_likes.filter(is_positive=True).values_list('likes_to', flat=True)
```

you'll have two lists of `user_id`s of which the intersection are the users that match. The `flat=True` is required to make two lists otherwise the keys in each list would be different and the intersection empty:

```
matches = CustomUser.objects.filter(id__in=qs1.intersection(qs2))
```

or if you just want the list of ids:

```
match_ids = qs1 & qs2
```

This gives you all the users that have a match with the `request.user`.